# Visio edit data graphic properties

Tags: graphics, visio

I use Visio 2016 which lets me add data graphics to my shapes. For example I can add a text label and customise it to some degree.

I'd like to have a text label with a red background on the left side of the shape and another with a green background on the right side, however the fill type only lets me choose between one color or no color at all.

The only function I found lets me adjust the color of the shape which doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have set fill type as "Filled" you need to right click the text label and set it's fill color as mentioned here https://blogs.office.com/2013/05/30/data-linked-diagrams-multiple-data-graphics-with-a-single-shape/ "If you want to change the fill of the data graphic, select that element and change the fill as you would for any other shape." Just make sure that you are actually selecting the text label and not the shape.
[see sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vatby.png)

Comment: How do I select the text label?

Comment: You can make the initial position of the text label something like FarLeft to make it easier to select. When you click the text label the first time, it selects the shape, but if you click it again it selects the label.

Comment: When I select it again it just deselects the shape. Strangely only one out of eight data graphic text fields has a yellow dot to move it around, however I can't select that either.

Comment: That's strange, when if I click the text label again it let's me edit it, change the size, change the color, are you able to move the text label around. Try making sure that you are clicking the text label itself and not the shape. hope this helps..

Comment: It looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/TgQchLu.png) at the moment. As you can see I can only move the right label around, I can't select it and change its properties though. Even when I open the list of data graphic fields and click on a field it selects it in the drawing but I can't do anything else.

Comment: OK. Let's try this, Enable the "Developer" tab on the menu item see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb608625.aspx. Select the shape, then go to Developer>Behavior>Group Behavior>Selection, change the drop down to "Group First", [link] (http://imgur.com/pNgjUGZ), and say OK. Now you should be able to select the graphic field by double-clicking (hopefully :) )

Comment: Awesome it works, thanks. Now is it possible to automate the process for the same type of text field in every sheet? :)